# How to make a table in SQL that tracks people entered by the hour, but also stores the date?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using an HikVision Dual Lens People Counting Camera that tracks the amount of people that enter/exit a location by the hour. The data that is exported from the camera is automatically put into an excel file with the format being as follows:

| Time Entered | People Entered |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:00.000 | 43 |
| 01:00:00.000 | 87 |
| 02:00:00.000 | 62 |

The file is then uploaded to my website and put into the database under the same format. However, it isn't good enough since I want to be able to query the data based on a specific day, for example how many people entered on every Monday, how many people entered from 2/10/2022 to 2/19/2022, etc. I have been trying to figure out a way for my table to have the date ALONG with the breakdown by hour, so for example:

2022-02-19 00:00:00
2022-02-19 01:00:00
2022-02-19 02:00:00
2022-02-19 03:00:00

My issue is, the software for the camera builds the excel sheet and conforms to the table above, and has no spot to include the date. I was wondering how I could get the date and the hourly breakdown of people entered all into one database so that I can query anything I need.

Sorry if this is a little incomprehensible, it's hard explaining my exact issue. I can provide updates if need be! Thank you so much for any and all help!!

Comment: If the spreadsheet contains no date, can you use the timestamp of the file to determine the date it applies to?

Comment: Can you plan a task at midnight to get the days entries?

Comment: @kmoser that might be possible, given its an excel file, i also can add a section when the user imports the file to include the date, I just don't know how to transfer that to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot act on the system that generates the records in your database, a good option could be to add a date field to your table in order to get the day when the records were inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD day DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Comment: So you're saying if I already have a table of the format I listed above, I can just alter the table and it should work? 

Let me try editing it with MariaDB! Thank you

Comment: That worked very well! Now all I need to do is figure out how to get the dates to fill properly, since right now they're all just 0s